# Copy worksheet from cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm looking to copy a worksheet from a closed workbook in another location. The worksheet would be dependent on a cell reference. For example if I had the name 'Employee list 'in cell A1 then the code would search for that worksheet and copy it. If that cell was to change to 'new employee list' then the code would search and copy the worksheet with that name. I have tried using the code below without success, any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
Sub CopySheet()
   
 Dim strSheetName As String 
   
 strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
 With Workbooks.Open("C:\path") 
   
 DoEvents '//// ensure workbook is open
    
 .Worksheets(strSheetName).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  
     
 .Close False 
   
 End With
    
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "without success", what happens?

Comment: hi, It comes up with a 'run-time error '9', subscript out of range for the line .Worksheets(strSheetName).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Comment: Then obviously, the sheet doesn't exist. Have you checked the content of `strSheetName` with the debugger? May a simple spelling error? How do you want to ensure that cell A1 holds a valid sheet name?

Comment: Hi, I copied one of the sheet names to cell A1, yeah checked the content with the debugger

Comment: Well, the possible causes are:  `The path supplied is incorrect`, `The extension of excel file in the path is incorrect`, `sheet name could be wrong`, `the workbook being accessed is password protected.`